# See unzipped data for a specific stream into http2

Tags: wireshark, http2

With wireshark, on windows, I know how to follow a http1.1 stream and see the unzipped data.
I know how to follow http2 and decode ssl, but I don't know how to get a specific stream and unzipped the content of the stream.

Use case browsing a website, on the stream 1 the html (I need to see the content unzipped) then on other stream some resource js css,  need to get the unzipped content of the js.

Any tips ?

Comment: Some more context would be useful. Like what exactly are you monitoring, an unzip operation happening over the network? What OS are you on? What other traffic do you have there that you need to separate your stream from? That could determine if the answer is for example to bind your browser/application to a specific interface and then capture with Wireshark on that one.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff I have added some details

Comment: With http1.1, doing follow tcp stream you have the zipped content, doing follow http stream you have the content unzipped, I am looking for the same on http2